# CSS Drop down Menu in WP

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm traying to edit this css to make a drop down menu when you mouse over a link. Trying to use :hover and change a display to none, but don't have this effect.
It's "Easy Sidebar Menu Widget" for WP, but i don't have much experience with that.
Please give me advice.

CSS:

```
@font-face{
  font-family:'widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget';
  src:url("../fonts/fontello.eot?35265427");
  src:url("../fonts/fontello.eot?35265427#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("../fonts/fontello.woff2?35265427") format("woff2"),url("../fonts/fontello.woff?35265427") format("woff"),url("../fonts/fontello.ttf?35265427") format("truetype"),url("../fonts/fontello.svg?35265427#fontello") format("svg");
  font-weight:normal;font-style:normal
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget ul{
  list-style-type:none
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget .current-menu-item>span>a,.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget .current-menu-ancestor>span>a{
  font-weight:700
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item{
  position:relative;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border-bottom:0px solid #eee;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .link__wrap{
  position:relative;
  display:block
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item a{
  display:block;
  padding:8px 0px;
  width:100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item a .nav_desc{
  display:block;
  color:#777
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler{
  position:absolute;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  top:2px;
  right:0px;
  width:34px;
  height:34px;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  text-align:center;
  outline:none;
  font-size:12px;
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler i{
  font-family:"widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget";
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
  speak:none;color:#555;
  text-decoration:inherit;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  line-height:34px;
  display:block;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler i:before{
  content:'\e800'
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler.toggle__open i:before{
  content:'\e801'
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler,.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler:focus{
  background:rgba(239,239,239,0.4);
  border:1px solid #eee
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children .easy-sidebar-menu-widget-link{
  padding-right:40px
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .sub-menu{
  display:none;
  position:relative;
  margin-left: -25px
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .sub-menu li:first-child{
  border-top:0px solid #eee
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .sub-menu li:first-child:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:-8px;
  top:-8px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-left:5px solid transparent;
  border-right:5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:8px solid #eee
}
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item .sub-menu li:last-child{
  border-bottom:0px
}
```

Comment: It looks like minification works pretty well.

Comment: Why do you need to change the css for a menu widget to get it to work? Are you sure you've set up the widget properly? Have you included and called all the javascript?

Comment: Menu widget is working well, but i need to change one thing: now menu is dropping down on click, I want to drop down menu when you mouse over a link. It's possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work as we don't have the html structure but try to add this line to your css:

```
.widget_easy_sidebar_menu_widget li.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```